# If condition to check values exist in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like below

```
    data = [
     {
        "Payment_type":1,
        "amount":10000
     },

     {
        "Payment_type":1,
        "amount":40000
     },
     {
        "Payment_type":2,
        "amount":10000
     },
     {
        "Payment_type":2,
        "amount":20000
     }
]
```

Now I need check to if `Payment_type = 1` then get all amounts of Payment_type 1, else get all amounts with other payment type

I need output like

```
   Payment type 1
       ---10000
       ---40000
   Payment type 2
       ---10000
       ---20000
```

I have tried with below code

```
   foreach($data as $d)
   {
       if($d->Payment_type == 1)
       {
           echo $d->amount;
       }
       else
       {
           echo $d->amount;
       }
   }
```

How can I get those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly echoing the amount after finding out whether the data is type 1 or 2, you can fill up 2 arrays (type 1 and type 2). And then, *later*, iterate over those arrays. This way, the data is going to be sorted by type. My example will have output exactly like in your question.

```
$dataOfType1 = array();
$dataOfType2 = array();

foreach($data as $d)
{
   if($d->Payment_type == 1)
   {
       $dataOfType1[] = $d;
   }
   else
   {
       $dataOfType2[] = $d;
   }
}

// iterate over first array (type 1)
echo "Payment type 1 <br>";
foreach($dataOfType1 as $d){
  echo "---".$d->amount . "<br>";
}

// iterate over second array (type 2)

echo "Payment type 2 <br>";
foreach($dataOfType2 as $d){
  echo "---".$d->amount . "<br>";
}
```

**edit:** moving the payment-type headers outside of loops

Answer (score 0):

With a function that I wrote from my self-written class [GrumpyHelper](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyHelper/blob/master/grumpyhelper.php), there is a function that is called groupArray.

```
function groupArray($arr, $group, $preserveSubArrays = false, $preserveGroupKey = false) {
    $temp = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $subarray) {
        $groupBy = $subarray[$group];
        if(!$preserveGroupKey) {
            unset($arr[$key][$group]);
        }
        if(!array_key_exists($groupBy, $temp)) {
            $temp[$groupBy] = array();
        }
        if(!$preserveSubArrays && count($arr[$key])==1) {
            $temp[$groupBy][] = current($arr[$key]);
        } else {
            $temp[$groupBy][] = $arr[$key];
        }
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

You can plug your data into this function, like this:

```
print_r(groupArray($data, "Payment_type", false, false));
```

Which will get you the result as:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10000
            [1] => 40000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10000
            [1] => 20000
        )

)
```

Where the key is equal to the what was originally `Payment_type`.

Now you just have to loop through to get the totals.

```
$totals = [];
foreach($data_from_groupArray as $key => $amounts) {
    foreach($amounts as $amount) {
        if(empty($totals[$key])) $totals[$key] = 0;
        $totals[$key] += $amount;
    }
}
```

This will give you the result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 50000
    [2] => 30000
)
```

Where the key is equal to the former `Payment_type`, and the value is equal to all of the amounts added together.

Or, for the output you specified above, do this instead of the loop above:

```
foreach($data_from_groupArray as $key => $amounts) {
    echo "Payment type {$key} <br>";
    foreach($amounts as $amount) {
        echo "   ---{$amount}<br>";
    }
}
```

Note: This code will work no matter how many different `Payment_type`'s you have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in the order presented (i.e. arrays are sorted on payment_type), this would work to:

```
<?php
    $data = array(array("Payment_type"=>1,"amount"=>10000),
                  array("Payment_type"=>1,"amount"=>40000),
                  array("Payment_type"=>2,"amount"=>10000),
                  array("Payment_type"=>2,"amount"=>20000)
                 );

    #var_dump($data);
    $currenttype = 0;
    foreach($data as $d)
    {
        if ($currenttype != $d['Payment_type'])
        {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Payment type $d[Payment_type]<br>";
            $currenttype=$d['Payment_type'];
        }

        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;---$d[amount]<br>";
   }
?>
```

The `&nbsp;` are to give you exactly the output you want, but this is better done with CSS in real life.

Output:

```
    Payment type 1
        ---10000
        ---40000
    Payment type 2
        ---10000
        ---20000
```

Comment: `Assuming your data is in the order presented` - I think this assumption is wrong. As I read the question, it asks about how to group those echos by payment-type. But it could be that I'm wrong.

Comment: Indeed, that part was not specified, I just went with the data as presented.  Of course, solutions as yours that do not care about order are better.

Answer (score 0):

create function which takes `$id` as an argument and returns filtered data:

```
function get_by_type($id, $array){
    $arr = array();
    foreach($array as $a){
        if($a['Payment_type'] == $id){
                array_push($arr, $a);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```